# Run Cucumber runners in parallel with IntelliJ JUnit Run Configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, junit, cucumber

I'm building a test automation project that is using Java and Cucumber 7.15. I'm on IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2.
I have a few Cucumber runner classes that point to a different feature file tag which means that each runner runs a different set of feature files.

What I want to achieve is to run those Cucumber runners in parallel. That way feature file sets are ran at the same time but feature files inside those sets are ran sequentially. I achieved it by using parallel execution in Surefire plugin but I want to do it with IntelliJ JUnit Run Configuration so I can have a neat live view of what scenarios are being executed.

With the help of ChatGPT I came up with a `CustomTestSuite` class that integrates the runners and then I tried running it through JUnit Run Cofniguration but runners are ran sequentially. I don't see any parallel run option in Run Configuration menu.

```
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.Suite;

@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
        Runner1.class,
        Runner2.class
})
public class CustomTestSuite {
}
```

Is this even possible? Lack of information online leads me to believe that I'm trying something impossible here.

Comment: You can not do this in IDEA.

Comment: M.P. Korstanje I suspected that's probably the case - thank you.

Comment: Not sure if this helps: paral exec only supported by create a Maven run configuration:  
https://jbs.zendesk.com/attachments/token/wkX12eZAbttYFTB4bGYlXmiCX/?name=image.png
  
The final execution cmd is like this: **... org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher -Didea.version=2023.3.4 -T 4 test**  
  
You can specify the tests to be run like:  
mvn test -D test=$ClassName_#$MethodName_  
  
The gutter icon can only create IDEA Java run tests, so it's not possible to specify mvn run params.  
Or maybe https://cucumber.io/docs/guides/parallel-execution/?lang=java?

Comment: Jacky Liu
What I wanted to achieve is to run Cucumber runners in parallel with JUnit Run Configuration but now I know it is not possible.
Like I said in the question - I managed to achieve this with Maven Surefire plugin so I am aware of your solution. Thank you anyway :]